# Does Azure Cosmos DB supports RDF schema and SPARQL?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I have a requirement in which i need to design a solution to load data from source to knowledge graph. Also its mentioned that database should support RDF or Graph Database schema and SPARQL engine. SO I am not sure whether to use Cosmos DB graph database for this solution as they mentione d Knowledge graph is the destination.
Could anyone please help whether Cosmos DB supports RDF schema and SPARQL as i didn't get any concrete answer for this anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Cosmos DB Gremlin does not support RDF.
You can vote for it here: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/d5734c02-555b-ed11-a81b-000d3ae49307